# Битрикс24 не возвращает нужных данных при событии Обновление задачи (ONTASKUPDATE)

Tags: битрикс, битрикс24

Настроил исходящий вебхук с событием *Обновление задачи (ONTASKUPDATE)*. Согласно [этому методу](https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/rest_help/tasks/events_tasks/ontaskupdate.php):
`FIELDS_AFTER - поля задачи после события`. В случае отсутствия доступных полей задачи данное поле будет содержать значение undefined.

А вот какие данные приходят при обновлении задачи:

`[('event', 'ONTASKUPDATE'), ('data[FIELDS_BEFORE][ID]', '96892'), ('data[FIELDS_AFTER][ID]', '96892'), ('data[IS_ACCESSIBLE_BEFORE]', 'undefined'), ('data[IS_ACCESSIBLE_AFTER]', 'undefined'), ('ts', '1590168425'), ('auth[domain]', 'domain.bitrix24.ru'), ('auth[client_endpoint]', 'https://domain.bitrix24.ru/rest/'), ('auth[server_endpoint]', 'https://oauth.bitrix.info/rest/'), ('auth[member_id]', '8ba...869'), ('auth[application_token]', 'nas...d8h')]`

Поддержка Битрикс24 не оказывает поддержки по API:

> Такие консультации оказывают наши партнёры, которые занимаются внедрением, настройкой и доработкой Битрикс24 под индивидуальные запросы клиентов.

API Б24 кривое или я что-то упустил в документации?

Answer (score 1):

спустя две недели, Б24 всё-таки ответил.
вопрос задавал через партнёра.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]